# Android - Error inflating SimonVT NumberPicker class in my layout xml

Tags: android, numberpicker

I've been at this for days now, and I am at the point of giving up, so any help is much appreciated!

I've been trying to implement the [simonVT numberpicker](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker) in my android app. Completely new to android, so including the library, referencing this library and getting everything to compile has been a few days mission in itself. Now I finally have everything compiling I get the following error at runtime:

```
04-06 10:58:37.126: E/AndroidRuntime(14324): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.goalminder/com.example.goalminder.AddGoal}:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #81: 
Error inflating class net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker
```

Here is the opening of my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/net.simonvt.numberpicker"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

**NB** - The 'xmlns:app' part above has a yellow warning marker - it's not being used. I included this per another stackoverflow answer re. a similar problem. Have left in to discourage this suggestion.

Here is the xml for the numberpicker:

```
<net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker          
    android:id="@+id/dayPicker"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

I have included the theme as instructed by Simon in my theme file. I wasn't really sure what name to give it, so I called it 'NumberPicker':

```
<resources>

    <!-- Copy one of these attributes to your own theme (choose either dark or light).
        <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.NumberPicker</item>
       <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.Light.NumberPicker</item>
    -->
    <style name="NumberPicker" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.NumberPicker</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NumberPicker" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.Light.NumberPicker</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I have also added the following to my android manifest as a child of application:

```
 <activity 
     android:name="net.simonvt.numberpicker.Numberpicker" />
 <activity 
     android:name="net.simonvt.numberpicker.Scroller" />
```

I've been all over stackoverflow, so what we have above is a scatter gun approach of everything I have seen recommended so. As stated before, I'm floundering with this and am close to implementing a standard ugly list.

**NB** - I got all this working with the native android implementation of Numberpicker. I want to use Simon VT's backport version however as I will be looking to support API < 11, which includes Gingerbread which I believe has a [39.7% distribution](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html). Please let me know if you think I don't need to support this far back.

Comment: Any news on this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I went for using the native Numberpicker implementation. I've accepted the response below though as also got same response from SimonVT on his github. Give that a shot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need add theme for the activity on AndroidManifest.xml: 
Example:

```
<activity android:name="yourActivity" android:theme="@style/SampleTheme.Light"/>
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I'm trying to use the NumberPicker in a Dialog and I'm using getActivity().setTheme(R.style.AppBaseTheme); but nothig. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Emiliosg no need to do any extra work, just set theme for activity that dialog should be shown in it

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to create a theme for your own project, you may do the following to the source code of numberpicker to set it to use the default theme NPWidget_Holo_numberPicker.

Replace the constructor with the following

```
public NumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, R.style.NPWidget_Holo_NumberPicker);
}
```

then change the assignment of TypedArray attributesArray to the following:

```
    TypedArray attributesArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, R.styleable.NumberPicker, 0, defStyle);
```

Answer (score 2):

See Simon's usage notes:

> Requires adding a single attribute to your theme. Check the sample app for how this is done.

[`values/theme.xml`](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker/blob/master/samples/res/values/themess.xml):

```
<style name="SampleTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.NumberPicker</item>
</style>
```

[`values-v11/themes.xml`](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker/blob/master/samples/res/values-v11/themes.xml):

```
<style name="SampleTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.NumberPicker</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker with com.your.package.NumberPicker.

Answer (score 0):

I was having practically the same problem, I was getting the error

```
11-18 21:13:18.627: W/ResourceType(13799): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
```

I finally realised that I had to add the style item into my *own* style definitions (as Paul Lammertsma shows above) as I was just copy/pasting SimonVT's styles, which of course my application wasn't using:

```
<style parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" name="NoActionBar">
    <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.NumberPicker</item>
</style>
```

Then, after it still not working, I found I'd completely missed a themes.xml file (I have three for different API levels).